# deleting Expired client secret of app registration in azure using a power shell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have extracted the expired client secrets of app registration using graph api. how can i create a power shell script using that Json output of the graph api to delete the expired client secrets.

i created a power shell script to delete the expired client secret using the json output of graph api. but the script is not deleting the expired secret instead its showing as the secret does not exist.

Below is the script that that is used.

```
# Provide the path to the JSON file
$jsonFilePath = "C:\Users\habeebullah.abdullah\Desktop\Test"

# Read JSON data from the file
$jsonData = Get-Content $jsonFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json

# Create a worklog array to store deletion information
$worklog = @()

# Current time
$currentTime = Get-Date

# Function to delete secrets
function DeleteSecret($secretInfo) {
    # Implement your secret deletion logic here
    # For example:
    $Remove-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential -ObjectId $secretInfo.Id -KeyId $secretInfo.KeyId

    # Add an entry to the worklog
    $worklogEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Id = $secretInfo.Id
        DisplayName = $secretInfo.DisplayName
        DeletedAt = (Get-Date)
    }
    $worklog += $worklogEntry
}

# Iterate through secrets and delete expired ones
$jsonData | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.DaysLeft -lt 0) {
        DeleteSecret $_
    }
}

# Log the worklog
$worklog | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Save the worklog as a CSV file in the same location as the JSON file
$worklog | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Users\habeebullah.abdullah\Desktop\Test\worklog.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

below is the json input for the above script:

```
 {
    "Id": "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYYXXY",
    "DisplayName": null,
    "StartDateTime": "2019-07-08T17:46:31.9726727+00:00",
    "EndDateTime": "2021-07-08T17:46:31.9726727+00:00",
    "ODataType": "microsoft.graph.passwordCredential",
    "Context": null,
    "AppRegistration": {
      "DisplayName": "ABCDEFGHIJKL",
      "CreatedDateTime": "2019-07-08T17:46:32+00:00",
      "AppId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "ODataType": "#microsoft.graph.application"
    },
    "DaysLeft": -811
  }
```

Comment: Could you please include the script that you have tried in your question?

Comment: Script included

Comment: Could you print the value `ObjectId `:`$secretInfo.Id` and `KeyId `:`$secretInfo.KeyId` and check if the values are correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the below script to delete the expired client secret using the json output make use of below:

My json [input](https://i.imgur.com/MF2YWCW.png):

```json
[
    {
        "KeyId":  "3296a154-c429XXXXXX",
        "DisplayName":  null,
        "StartDateTime":  "\/Date(1694081768648)\/",
        "EndDateTime":  "\/Date(1694111400000)\/",
        "ODataType":  "microsoft.graph.passwordCredential",
        "Context":  null,
        "AppRegistration":  {
                                "AppId":  "bacc9e56-790b-41e0xxxxxx",
                                "CreatedDateTime":  "\/Date(1687163750000)\/",
                                "DisplayName":  "Bxxxxxx",
                                "ODataType":  "#microsoft.graph.application"
                            },
        "DaysLeft":  -66
    },
```

In my app registration I have an expired client secret like below:

[image]

When I ran the below script, in my App registration all expired client secrets are deleted successfully.

```
# Provide the path to the JSON file
$jsonFilePath = "C:Yourjsonfilepath"

# Connect to Azure account (You may need to adjust this if you're using a different authentication method)
Connect-AzAccount

# Read JSON data from the file
$jsonData = Get-Content $jsonFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json

# Create a worklog array to store deletion information
$worklog = @()

# Function to delete secrets
function DeleteSecret($secretInfo) {
    # Debug: Print AppId and KeyId before attempting to remove the credential
    Write-Host "Deleting secret for AppId: $($secretInfo.AppRegistration.AppId) and KeyId: $($secretInfo.KeyId)"

    # Connect to Azure account (You may need to adjust this if you're using a different authentication method)
    Connect-AzAccount

    # Implement your secret deletion logic here
    # For example:
    Remove-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationId $secretInfo.AppRegistration.AppId -KeyId $secretInfo.KeyId

    # Add an entry to the worklog
    $worklogEntry = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Id = $secretInfo.KeyId
        DisplayName = $secretInfo.DisplayName
        DeletedAt = (Get-Date)
    }
    $worklog += $worklogEntry
}

# Iterate through each item in the JSON array
foreach ($secretInfo in $jsonData) {
    if ($secretInfo.DaysLeft -lt 0) {
        DeleteSecret $secretInfo
    }
}

# Log the worklog
$worklog | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Save the worklog as a CSV file in the same location as the JSON file
$worklog | Export-Csv -Path "C:\xxxxxxx" -NoTypeInformation
```

***Output***:

[image]

To confirm in portal client secrets are deleted like below:

[image]